# cron - log file not being written to after a certain time?

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

I have a `script` running via `crontab`

It runs perfectly till a certain time and `print` statements show up in the `log` file.
After this particular time, the log file doesn't have any more entries.

I checked whether the `script` is still running:

```
ps aux | grep script_name
```

Shows in the results:

```
>ubuntu   19748  0.0  0.0   4636   820 ?        Ss   09:15   0:00 /bin/sh -c python3 /home/ubuntu/ib/op_script/process.py > /home/ubuntu/logs/process.log 2>&1
>ubuntu   19751  0.1  9.4 812908 381100 ?       Sl   09:15   0:23 python3 /home/ubuntu/ib/op_script/process.py
>ubuntu   23161  0.0  0.0  14860  1080 pts/0    S+   13:57   0:00 grep --color=auto process
```

I checked the free memory:

```
free -h
```

Output:

```
 total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.8G        1.4G        208M         12M        2.2G        2.1G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

I am not sure how to check what the error might be, or if the script is still doing its functions just not writing to the `log` file.

Note: the functions are repetitive in a `while` loop and have run multiple times before.
I am not sure what would be the reason for no `print` statements coming

Comment: Run the script on its own without redirecting output and see if it dies.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` env var to turn off output buffering? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering

Answer (score 0):

A few steps to check:

1. Check if there is entry in `/var/log/syslog`

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

This will show what commands were run by cron.

2. Check if there is anything in mail

```
tail /var/mail/<the username you setup cron job>
```

by default cron redirect sys outputs to mail.

3. independent cron log can be enabled by remove the comment of line
   `#cron.*                         /var/log/cron.log`
   in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`

Hopefully these information can help you locate the issue.